# How to get month-to-date excluding today (month to yesterday?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to find month-to-yesterday in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Sum(subtotal), 0) 
FROM   dbo.dr_trans 
WHERE  transdate >= Dateadd(d, 0, Datediff(dd,0,Dateadd(dd,-(Day(Getdate()) 
                    - 1 ), Getdate())))
```

This gives me month to date BUT includes today. Is it as simple as changing the `-1` to `-2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this condition this way:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(SUBTOTAL),0)
FROM dbo.DR_TRANS
WHERE TRANSDATE >= CAST(GETDATE() - DAY(GETDATE()) + 1 AS DATE) AND
      TRANSDATE < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

Comment: OK, query works, but data returned is not what I expected. I will do some forensics and verify data. Thanks so far... +1 to you.

Comment: OK, I had missed another qualifier which fixes the data value for me. So you were right and thanks.